# mariasql install error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

When I try to install mariasql I got this error.

> Node ver:4.1.1
>
> npm ver: 2.14.4
>
> gyp ver:3.0.3
>
> C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c(31):
>   error C2373: '__pfnDliNot
>
> ifyHook2': redefinition; different type modifiers
>   [C:\Users\Миша\node_modules\mariasql\build\deps\libmariadbclient\zlib
>
> \zlib.vcxproj]
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   14.0\VC\include\delayimp.h(134): note: see declaration of '__pfnDliNot
>      ifyHook2'
>
> gyp ERR! build error
>
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
>
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
>
> gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js"
>   "rebuild"
>
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Миша\node_modules\mariasql
>
> gyp ERR! node -v v4.1.1
>
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
>
> gyp ERR! not ok
>
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
>
> npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   "mariasql"
>
> npm ERR! node v4.1.1
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! mariasql@0.2.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the mariasql@0.2.6 install script 'node-gyp
>   rebuild'.
>
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mariasql package,
>
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
>
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>
> npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
>
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
>
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls mariasql
>
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Миша\npm-debug.log

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reply even if it's been a long time since the creation of your question

I encountered this problem and I saw on the web that it was related to python

In your PATH environment, check your version and if it's a Python 3.X set it to Python 2.7 and the problem will be solved !